# libwebsocket: how to constuct lextable for cookie field

Tags: c, websocket

I write the websocket server via libwebsocket. I need Cookie field to valid user. there is a array named lextable[]  for parse http header . I don't know how to modify lextable for Cookie filed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, go to "lib" directory in your libwebsockets dir. Find the "minilex.c" file, open it with your favorite text editor. At the beginning of the file you will see the "set" string array. You only need to add the line "Cookie: " at the end.
The next step is compiling the program "minilex.c" with command `gcc minilex.c -o minilex`.
When the compilation is finished, run the binary file and you will see a console consisting of two-dimensional array with the HEX codes of letters and their positions.
Copy-past it into "parsers.c" file.